# Configure Live Reload on a Ionic project based on the generator-gulp-angular

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, gulp, gulp-livereload

I have an Ionic 1.3.1 project with an architecture based on the, old but gold, generator-gulp-angular in which I would like to enable `Live Reload` on the device (Android).

My gulp config paths look like:

```
exports.paths = {
  src: 'src',
  dist: 'www',
  tmp: '.tmp',
  e2e: 'e2e'
};
```

This means that to run the project in the browser I use `gulp serve` and to run in the Android device I use `gulp build && ionic run android`.

I can't use the command `ionic run android --livereload` [as described in the doc here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/run.html) because it synchronizes the `www` folder where (after a `gulp build`) I have the minified files and not the source files.

So I would like to mix up in some way the two commands `gulp serve` and `ionic run android --livereload` but sincerely I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: hello,
you can check this link https://codepen.io/leob6/post/quick-tip-using-gulp-to-customize-the-serve-run-and-build-process-for-your-ionic-framework-apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved updating my `gulp watch` task that every time there's a change it runs the `gulp build` while the command `ionic run android --livereload` is running.

I added a flag `--livereload` to my `gulp watch`, so my `/gulp/watch.js` file looks like:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['inject'], function () {

  var livereload = process.argv.length === 4 && process.argv[3] === '--livereload';

  gulp.watch([path.join(conf.paths.src, '/*.html'), 'bower.json'], ['inject-reload']);

  gulp.watch([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.css'),
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.scss'),
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/scss/*.scss')
  ], function(event) {
    if (livereload) {
      gulp.start('build');
    } else {
      if(isOnlyChange(event)) {
        gulp.start('styles-reload');
      } else {
        gulp.start('inject-reload');
      }
    }
  });

  gulp.watch(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.js'), function(event) {
    if (livereload) {
      gulp.start('build');
    } else {
      if(isOnlyChange(event)) {
        gulp.start('scripts-reload');
      } else {
        gulp.start('inject-reload');
      }
    }
  });

  gulp.watch(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.html'), function(event) {
    if (livereload) {
      gulp.start('build');
    } else {
      browserSync.reload(event.path);
    }
  });
});
```

How to use:

on a terminal tab:

```
ionic run android --livereload
```

and, on another terminal tab:

```
gulp watch --livereload
```

Enjoy!